# Transparent div not working properly

Tags: html, css, opacity, transparent

I am trying to add a div with transparent property .

```
.products
{
    width:280px;
    height:320px;
    float:left;
    background:#fff;
    margin:5px;
}
.products:hover
{
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px #ccc;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px#ccc;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px #ccc;
}
.p_desc
{
    height:120px;
    background:#666;
    opacity:0.6;
    filter:alpha(opacity=60);
}
```

The HTML :

```
<div class="products">
                <img src="css/images/products/3m_1440.jpg" />
                    <div class="p_desc">This is a good product</div>
                </div>
```

Image size is `280x320px` . I am expecting the class `p_desc` to transparent within div `products`  .But result is its transparent but not withing the `products`,its overflowing !

[image]

Comment: so the description should fully cover the image? or do you want aling it to the top/bottom?

Comment: The title of the question is a bit misleading, since the fact that the div is transparent doesn't affect the layout problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give `position:absolute` to your `.p_desc`.

write this:

```
.products
{
    width:280px;
    height:320px;
    float:left;
    background:#fff;
    margin:5px;
    position:relative;
}
.p_desc
{
    height:120px;
    background:#666;
    opacity:0.6;
    filter:alpha(opacity=60);
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please go through this code.I hope it'll solve your problem.
http://jsfiddle.net/4hLnZ/12/